# Vue: Performing an async request in mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

When a user refreshes a page the function 'retrieveUserData' should be executed in 'mounted'. However this function returns a promise and for some reason the page keeps infinitely loading whenever I try to execute that function in the mounted/created lifecycle of this component. Is this not possible? Is it not possible to perform async functions in mounted/created?

Thanks in advance!

```
// App.vue

private mounted() {
    this.fetchAllData();
}

public fetchAllData() {
    try {
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageTokenLocation)) {
            console.log("test1");
            this.retrieveUserData().then((userData) => {
                ...
            });
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

private retrieveUserData() {
    return axios.request({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${this.url}/v1/user`
    });
}
```

Comment: Axios returns a promise because the entire library works with promises. Your `then` should still be resolved though. If it is not resolved you should check what your network request is actually doing. Are you receiving a 200 status code or not? It is perfectly ok to make an async call from a created or mounted hook.

Comment: Network request is used in other parts of code and works fine. Only here it keeps loading infinitely. Not getting any response to the request...

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: If the server is not returning any type of response then likely there is something wrong with the request or an error on the remote server. The fact that it is in the mounted function shouldn't change whether you get a response or not. You could test this pretty quickly but just throwing in a button that calls retrieveUserData()... in any case I don't see any reason that an axios call would time out in mounted and not elsewhere.

Comment: If i put the method in a button everything works fine. When in the 'mounted' the whole thing loops infinitely. The promise never resolves I guess... No clue :) 
I have no idea how to make a codepen or something alike for vue, otherwise I could try to make an example.